# How to populate the combobox with the header Text of the datagrid dynamically in flex 4?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have a button "get data" on clicking which my data grid gets populated. I want to populate the combobox at the same time with the column name of the data grid. On generating call, the result are getting stored in the last result, whihc then i am storing to the array .

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import mx.events.ListEvent;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

        import services.ServiceManager;

        import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;


        [Bindable] public var ArrColl_selectOptionComboBox:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection;
        [Bindable] public var SelectOption:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection;

        [Bindable] public var mainArrColl:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection;
        [Bindable] public var DGDataProvider:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection;
        [Bindable] public var DGDataProvider1:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection;

        public function clear():void
        {
            DGDataProvider = new ArrayCollection;
        }

        //clicking on the Get Data button to retrieve from the Jiraissue
        protected function button_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            getAllJiraissueResult2.token=jiraissueService1.getAllJiraissue();


        }

        protected function getAllJiraissueResult2_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
            mainArrColl = getAllJiraissueResult2.lastResult as ArrayCollection;
            DGDataProvider = mainArrColl;



        }









    //protected function Combobox_Option_changeHandler(event:ListEvent):void
        //{

                //myLabel.text = "You selected: " +  ComboBox(event.target).selectedItem.label;

                    //Value.prompt="Select Value";
                    //Value.selectedIndex=-1; // reset so prompt shows





        //}

        ]]>

</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <jiraissueservice1:JiraissueService1 id="jiraissueService1" fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)" showBusyCursor="true"/>
    <s:CallResponder id="getAllJiraissueResult2" result="getAllJiraissueResult2_resultHandler(event)"/>

    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:Button x="59" y="49" label="GET DATA"  id="button" click="button_clickHandler(event)"/>
<mx:DataGrid x="60" y="299" width="800" id="dataGrid" dataProvider="{DGDataProvider}">
    <mx:columns>

        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="pkey" dataField="pkey"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="PROJECT" dataField="pname"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="CREATED" dataField="CREATED"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="defectType" dataField="stringvalue"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Reporter" dataField="REPORTER"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="ASSIGNEE" dataField="ASSIGNEE"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="SLA" dataField="SLA"/>

    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>


<s:Button x="214" y="49" label="RESET" click="clear()"/>
<s:Button x="557" y="168" label="Button"/>

<mx:ComboBox id="Combobox_Option" width="201"   dataProvider="{SelectOption}" labelField="label" 
                prompt="Select Option"
                 x="59" y="169"/>
<mx:ComboBox id="Value" width="201"  labelField="label" 
                prompt="Select Value" dataProvider="{DGDataProvider1}"
                 x="308" y="169"/>
<s:Label id="myLabel" text="You selected:" fontWeight="bold" x="59" y="275"/>
```

Comment: specify your code, please

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly you just want to populate your combobox with datagrid's column names after getting the data. If it is so you can use "columns" property of your grid as dataprovider of the combobox. The "labelField" property should be set to "headerText". After clearing the grid you set the dataprovider of the cb to null.

Here is a simple code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
           minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.events.CollectionEvent;

        [Bindable]private var dp:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
            {artist:"Pavement",         album:"Slanted and Enchanted",  year:"2010",    price:39.1},
            {artist:"ABBA",             album:"Ring Ring",              year:"1973",    price:45.2},
            {artist:"The Betles",       album:"Please Please Me",       year:"1963",    price:29.1}]);

        private function onBtnLoad():void
        {
            myGrid.dataProvider = dp;

            cbCategories.dataProvider = myGrid.columns;
            cbCategories.labelField = "headerText";
        }

        private function onBtnReset():void
        {
            myGrid.dataProvider = null;

            cbCategories.selectedIndex = -1;
            cbCategories.dataProvider = null;
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>


<s:VGroup x="70" y="50">
    <s:DataGrid id="myGrid" width="420" height="100" >   
        <s:columns>
            <s:ArrayList>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="artist"    headerText="Artist's name" width="150"/>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="album"     headerText="Album"/>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="year"      headerText="Year" width="50"/>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="price"     headerText="Price" width="50"/>
            </s:ArrayList>
        </s:columns>       
    </s:DataGrid> 

    <s:HGroup>
        <s:Button id="btnLoad" label="Load Data" click="onBtnLoad()"/>
        <s:Button id="btnReset" label="Reset" click="onBtnReset()"/>
    </s:HGroup>

    <s:HGroup verticalAlign="bottom">
        <s:Label text="Categories:" width="70"/>
        <s:ComboBox id="cbCategories"/>
    </s:HGroup>
</s:VGroup>

</s:Application>
```